# MVC - How can I fill a table with data vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I would like to use c# to fill my HTML table with data where it stacks the data from top to bottom for 4 rows, and then adds on a new column with 4 more rows in the same way, continuing this pattern until there is no make data in the list.  To give a basic idea of what I mean by this:

**The C# list (a list of 8 "items"):**

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
for (var x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
    //Add 8 items to the list object
    items.Add("Item " + x.ToString());
}
```

**How a normal table works:**

```
[Item 1]|[Item 2]|[Item 3]|[Item 4]
[Item 5]|[Item 6]|[Item 7]|[Item 8]
```

**How I would like it to function:**

```
[Item 1]|[Item 5]
[Item 2]|[Item 6]
[Item 3]|[Item 7]
[Item 4]|[Item 8]
```

I have thought about a couple of ways to go about doing this, but none of my testing has gotten close to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Take a look at CSS's `column-*` properties (e.g., `column-count`, `column-rule`, &c.). Those will allow you to specify columns which your content will automatically be sorted into. It also has the advantage of being responsive, so it can collapse into a single column on smaller screens.

Comment: since you have tagged ASP.NET MVC, then it's best to adhere to MVC design pattern... in MVC, the Views are meant to have as little logic as possible (views are meant to be dumb)... their job is to display the model that the controller has built for them... so it's better to build your model (table) vertically in the controller and pass it to the view, as opposed to adding logic to the view to turn your model into a vertical table.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini So how can I do this in the controller?

Comment: You don't do it in the controller.  You do it in the view.  The controller just sends the list of 8 to the view.  How the 8 get displayed in an implementation detail for the view to handle.

Comment: @sjohn285: your question seems to be a simplified scenario, and I just gave you a general guideline about MVC... If the actual problem is as simple as this, then you can use some css formatting to display the result (as shown in the answer below)... if the problem is more complex, then you might want to build your model in Controller...

Comment: @HoomanBahreini In my example, I never stated whether the list object would be created in the view or the controller.  Ideally I would like to accomplish this using C# instead of CSS, but I guess if there is no "easy" way to do this using C# I've got no other choice.

Comment: @sjohn285: I suggest adding more details to your question and explaining why you need this to be done in C#. This might be an [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS and Flexbox to do this.  I used a `ul` and `li` but that could simply be a set of nested `div` also.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Try some stuff out here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox_skills

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 3em;
}

ul li {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```